# Swift downloading queue not working properly

Tags: swift, firebase

I have the following code to download a photo from Firebase:

```
    var imageFB : UIImage? = nil

    profilePicRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            guard let imageData = UIImage(data: data!) else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageFB = imageData
            }

        }).resume()

    })
```

When I step in into the code, I can see that the picture has been downloaded, however imageFB seems still to be zero after that block was executed. Xcode is saying 'The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.' when accessing detailed description of the photo during runtime. I guess it's a problem with the queue? Can anyone help me out with that?

I assume that there is a problem with the queue, so that the other block is executed before the photo could actually be downloaded.